# Need Help for Creating a view with the Below mentioned Scenario

Tags: sql

I need to know whether the following Scenario can be solved by creating a view

Introduction abt the Issue :

We have to Generate a Report for Non-Verified Address

We will Have a Two Location in Say. Reported Location and Completed Location. and StreetID for Both

Initial The Reported Location Address will be Store in DB with the Address Sequence No as 0 and if the Address is Verified / Already in the DB will have a StreetID for it . if its a New Address its StreetID will be Null

Once the Work Completed if the Completed Location Address is Different Then the Completed Location Address Will Move to Address Sequence NO  = 0  and the Reported Address will be moved to address Sequence  No = 1

if both address are same we will have only one record in db with the Sequence as 0 and streetid will be null if new address

to print in report we have to consider the SeqNo= 1

we need to take SeqNo = 0  if only both address are same

Scenarios :

1 .  If the SeqNo = 1 and StreetID is Not Null and SeqNo =0  and StreetID is Null we should not print the address

2 . if the SeqNo = 1 and StreetID is Null and SeqNo= 0 and StreetID is Not Null we should print the SeqNo = 1

1. if the SeqNo = 1 and StreetID is Null and SeqNo= 0 and StreetID is also Null we should print the SeqNo = 1
2. if only one sequence / record in db if the SeqNo =0  and StreetID is Null we need to print Seq = 0

i tried but the data for the scenario  = 1 is also being Printed. Actually the Data of Scenario  1 Should not Print.

can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would provide sample data noting under which scenario it should be selected or not selected, I may be able to provide a better answer than this one. However, let me be the first to take a shot at this.

`SELECT * 
    FROM <your_table>
    WHERE
        (SeqNo = 1 AND StreetID IS NULL)
        OR 
        (SeqNo = 0 AND StreetID IS NOT NULL)`